# Matplotlib Patch Confusion

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a little lost trying to plot the same patch collection across a collection of Subplots. my code at the moment is:

```
patches = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle([A[i], 20], (B[i]-A[i]), 10, ec="none")
    patches.append(rect)

collection = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)) 

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.plot(SOME STUFF)
ax1.add_collection(collection)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2.plot(SOME STUFF)
ax2.add_collection(collection)
```

If I just try to plot the collection in ax1 it works fine, but as soon as I add the line of code to add the collection to ax2 as well I get a figure generated with the subplots and the data correctly displayed but no patches.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I tested and get the same problem. It is like a collection is "linked" to an axis.
You may need to create two collections:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.collections as collections

# Position
P = np.random.uniform(0,1, (10,2))
# Size (width x height)
S = np.random.uniform(0.1,.2, (10,2))

patches = []
for i in range(len(P)):
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle(P[i], S[i,0], S[i,1])
    patches.append(rect)

collection1 = collections.PatchCollection(patches)
collection1.set_edgecolors('none')
collection1.set_facecolors('.75')

collection2 = collections.PatchCollection(patches)
collection2.set_edgecolors('none')
collection2.set_facecolors('.75')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect=1)
ax1.add_collection(collection1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect=1)
ax2.add_collection(collection2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: They are indeed linked to an axes. If you `import copy`, you can use 1 collection and add it with: `ax1.add_collection(copy.copy(collection1))`, you can add the same collection to other axes in a similar way.

Comment: Collections have a `_transOffset` property for their placement which prevents them from being in multiple axes at once. You can modify it with:
`collection1._transOffset = ax2.transData`, that would *move* it from the first to the second axes.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the code to create the collection, which I'd actually forgot to post. The workaround I found was to just repost that line within the code block for each subplot. Seems a little strange, but glad I wasn't going mad!